# use third part gem in rails application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am new in rais.

And I meet some problems when I want to use some third-part gems.

For example,I try to use 'cancan' in my system,and I am using rails 3.2.5 now.

When I install 'cancan' like this:

```
gem install cancan.
```

I found that it depends "activepack 3.2.6" which is not the same as what I am using(3.2.5)

So I wonder what will happen if I use 'cancan' in my application?

Also,how to import the 'cancan' to my cpp? Since in java I will put the related `.jar` file to the `/web-info/lib` path, and `import` it in the source code. How in ruby?

Comment: It will not run if it depends on actionpack 3.2.6. You can either either downgrade your cancan version which is compatable with actionpack 3.2.5 or upgrade your actionpack 3.2.6 like gem install actionpack -v3.2.6

Comment: And BTW, you should **really** upgrade to Rails 3.2.6 as it fixes some serious security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `gem install cancan`, you do not add this gem to your project, you just download and install it in system.

If you want to install gem in your app, write `gem 'cancan'` in your Gemfile (in your project folder), and then write `bundle install` in console. Bundle tries to solve all your gem dependencies and adds gem to your project. If your gems are incompatible, bundler will return error with description of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [bundler](http://gembundler.com/rails3.html) to manage your gem installation.

As far as version incompatibility goes, check Ahbay Kumar's answer.